# Forward email sent by a particular sender from Gmail

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I want to forward my mail from Gmail to another account but I don't want to forward all emails I want to forward just email sent by a particular sender.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

[Create a filter](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6579). You can do all sorts of clever things with them, including forwarding e-mail following certain rules.

Comment: Note that you'll need to verify the forwarding address is yours.